# Using :not in conjunction with adjacent selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have HTML like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="thumb">...</div>
    <div class="text">...</div>
</div>
```

I want the background of the "text" div to be white. But ONLY if there is no "thumb" div preceding it since that div won't always be there.

I realize I can do something like this:

```
.parent .text {background-color: #fff;}
.parent .thumb + .text {background-color: transparent;}
```

So color ALL the text backgrounds white and then override the ones that have the thumb div preceding it.

But I was wondering if it's possible to do something like:

```
.parent :not(.thumb +) .text {background-color: white;}
```

To kill two birds with one stone by only targeting the "text" div when there is no preceding "thumb" div. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditionals (if/else) in CSS using [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/):

```
$type: monster;
p {
  @if $type == ocean {
    color: blue;
  } @else if $type == matador {
    color: red;
  } @else if $type == monster {
    color: green;
  } @else {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

Check [documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_9)!

Or, you can use JavaScript/jQuery to add/remove classes according to whatever condition you need.

There is no actual if/else for standard CSS.

Answer (score -1):

The way you mention is already the way to target it only when there's no preceding div; `.thumb + .text {}` styles *only* apply when there is a `.thumb` element immediately preceding a `.text` element:

```css
.parent {
    background: grey;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.text {
    background: purple;
}

.thumb + .text {
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="thumb">...</div>
    <div class="text">White bg</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="text">White bg</div>
</div>
```